# align divs left and right next to each other

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure if i'm doing this right.

Trying to align divs left and right on same line, But when i resize window the right div drops down and stays to the right.

How would i re align the divs so that when i make the window smaller the right drops down and lines up with left div, maybe centre both divs?

Do i need to add them into a grid list with `<lu>`?

Also how would i align the phone numbers up?

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center!important;
}

.text-left {
  text-align: left!important;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right!important;
}

.right {
  float: right!important
}

.left {
  float: left!important
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <h2>Infomation:</h2>
  <p>
    Phone: (00) 00000000<br/> Fax: (00) 00000000<br/> Email: <a href="mailto:contact@email.com ">contact@email.com<br/></a>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="right text-right">
  <h2>Business Hours:</h2>
  <p>
    Monday - Thursday<br/> 8:30 - 5:00<br/> Friday <br/> 8:30 - 3:30<br/>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: why don't you try to use bootstrap? it makes ur life easier

Comment: @Salman i want to do things in pure html, css and javascript to learn how everything is done, less chance of things stuffing up.

Comment: Can you please bit more clear how you want to display when you resize the window?

Comment: if you are not use bootstrap, you must set your parent element with @media screen and the children elements too

Comment: @kannan as it is when i resize the right div drops down, it is still floating right. I would like it so that when one div drops down that the both align up. so both float left or centre both.

Comment: @nathan Sorry am still not clear what are you trying to say try out my answer solution and let me know is that what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using media queries for this. The logic is pretty simple. First, set the CSS rules for small screens. Then use a media query to apply new CSS rules for whenever the window is wider than a certain width.

```
.text-center {
  text-align: center!important;
}    
.text-left, .text-right {
  text-align: left!important;
}    
.left, .right {
  display: block;
}    
@media all and (min-width: 400px) {
  .left {
    float: left!important
  }
  .right {
    float: right!important
  }
  .text-right {
    text-align: right!important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how you want to display when you resize the window am assuming you want to display next to the first div so for that just .right css alone.

```
.right {
    float: left
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block;` to your `.left` and `.right` divs. Also, to get these divs always at left and right aligned even on small screen sizes, add `max-width: 49%;` in both.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

To make both divs on one line even when the window is smaller,
  just use following style and nothing else:

```
  <style>

div{
        float: left;
        width: 45%;
        padding: 2%;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap the info in another Div container(WrapperContainer) with set values like this.

```
<div class="WrapperContainer">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<h2>Infomation:</h2>
<p>
Phone: (00) 00000000<br/> Fax: (00) 00000000<br/> Email: <a  href="mailto:contact@email.com ">contact@email.com<br/></a>
</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<h2>Business Hours:</h2>
<p>
Monday - Thursday<br/> 8:30 - 5:00<br/> Friday <br/> 8:30 - 3:30<br/>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Then the style. Customize the with and height to fit your needs. if your resolution changes the container box will not so the results are stationary.

```
.WrapperContainer{
Width:800px;
height:300px;
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best approach in my point of view issmall screen first and  @media to decide when it should be send on both sides .

Here is a basic example, set at 680px, use any value you need. You can also add other break points.**(play the snippet ful page to see both boxes on a single line)**

Instead float, i used  flex and a wraper in the example to minimise code to write.

Use your float rules inside the media if you wish to keep it your way :)

```css
@media screen and (min-width:680px) {
  .box {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .text-right {
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<h style="font-size:3vw" 1>Play me full page and resize window</h1>
<div class="box">
  <div class="left">
    <h2>Infomation:</h2>
    <p>
      Phone: (00) 00000000<br/> Fax: (00) 00000000<br/> Email: <a href="mailto:contact@email.com ">contact@email.com<br/></a>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="right text-right">
    <h2>Business Hours:</h2>
    <p>
      Monday - Thursday<br/> 8:30 - 5:00<br/> Friday <br/> 8:30 - 3:30<br/>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make this responsive by using `bootstrap` for that you need to install bootstrap first and then use the following code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>Infomation:</h2>
      <p>
        Phone: (00) 00000000<br/> Fax: (00) 00000000<br/> Email: <a href="mailto:contact@email.com ">contact@email.com<br/></a>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>Business Hours:</h2>
      <p>
        Monday - Thursday<br/> 8:30 - 5:00<br/> Friday <br/> 8:30 - 3:30<br/>
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP does not want a bootstrap solution.