# aligning text in float right

Tags: html, css

Trying to align text that is in a div with float right

Trying at add tabs to my information, seems to be working with phone numbers, but if i'm floating it right it does not work.

Also when my screen is smaller then 400px the information text does not seem to be 100% centred.

The code:

```css
p span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

.responsive {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.responsive .left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.responsive .right {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  width: 50%;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .responsive .left,
  .responsive .right {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="left">
    <h2>Infomation:</h2>
    <p>
      <span>Phone:    </span>(00) 00000000<br/>
      <span>Fax:      </span>(00) 00000000<br/>
      <span>Email:    </span><a href="mailto:contact@email.com ">contact@email.com<br/></a>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <h2>Business Hours:</h2>
    <p>
      <span>Mon - Th:</span> 8:30 - 5:00<br/> <span>Friday:</span> 8:30 - 3:30<br/>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you want it aligned..?

Comment: @blackandorangecat well then the screen isbigger then 400px i want the days to have the same tabs as the numbers have. and when its smaller then 400 i want it all to be centred, at the moment its a little off centre.

Comment: Firstly, things are not appearing centered on smaller devices because you have defined width of `100px` on your `p span` elements. Use `padding` or `margin` instead.

In regards to the other issue, you need to provide more info on what you're after.

Comment: Yes, more (maybe less) info needed. I don't know what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

i'm going to use and update [answer i gave earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992820/align-divs-left-and-right-next-to-each-other#) with text-align:

```css
.box, h1 {
  text-align: center;/* update*/
  }
  .box {
  background:linear-gradient(to left, gray 50%, silver 50%) /* see center*/
}
.left p {display:table;
margin:auto;
text-align:left;
}.left p span {
display:inline-block;
padding-right:3em
}
.left p span:nth-child(3) {padding-right:4em;}
.left p span:last-of-type {padding-right:1em}

@media screen and (min-width:399px) {
  .box {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: left;/* update*/
  }
  .text-right {
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 style="font-size:3vw">Play me full page and resize window</h1>
<div class="box">
  <div class="left">
    <h2>Infomation:</h2>
    <p>
      <span>Phone:    </span>(00) 00000000<br/>
      <span>Fax:      </span>(00) 00000000<br/>
      <span>Email:    </span><a href="mailto:contact@email.com ">contact@email.com<br/></a>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="right text-right">
    <h2>Business Hours:</h2>
    <p>
      Monday - Thursday<br/> 8:30 - 5:00<br/> Friday <br/> 8:30 - 3:30<br/>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Im trying to add "tabs" so the numbers align and same as the days and time

Comment: @nathan use padding-right on spans .... sometimes it is also good to take a break and come back fresh later ;)

Comment: yeah i know, i just dont like giving up lol. when i use `padding-right: 100px;` with nothing else it just moves it right but does not align the numbers.

Comment: @nathan i updated the snippet with the padding idea ;)

Comment: oh so the real way to do it is set a padding for each line?

Comment: @Nathan, this is a way, not  the  ultimate :)

Comment: whats the ultimate way?

Comment: @nathan, there is none, You could use display, float, absolute positionning, width, whatever, ... what matters is your HTML structure(and also what you are willing to do with)  and the browsers where it is suppose to work.